# Angular, how to switch between production and development environments?

Tags: angular, environment, production

I have a big Angular application which is still needed in development, but already ready for use in production, I want to be switch between the states with simple change of

```
isProduction: boolean = false
```

to true,
I did it by making apiHelperService which is just usual service, it works fine for most application:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Response, Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class ApiHelperService {
  productionURL: string = 'http://35.203.121.40';
  developmentURL: string = 'http://10.25.37.523';
  serverUrl: string;
  apiPort: string = ':3000/';
  socketPort: string = ':2000/';
  isProductionMode: boolean = false;


  constructor() {
    this.serverUrl = this.isProductionMode ? this.productionURL : this.developmentURL;
  }

  getApiURL(): string {
    return this.serverUrl + this.apiPort;
  }

  getSocketUrl(): string {
    return this.serverUrl + this.socketPort;
  }
  getApiIp(): string {
    const serverIp = this.isProductionMode ? this.productionURL.split(':')[0] : this.developmentURL.split(':')[0];
    console.log('string url is:', serverIp);
    return serverIp;

  }
  serialize(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && ((obj[p] != null && obj[p] != '') || (typeof obj[p] == "boolean"))) {
        if (obj[p].length == 0) {
          continue;
        }
        else if (obj[p].length > 1 && typeof obj[p] == 'object') { // reformats arrays
          for (let i = 0; i < obj[p].length; i++) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p][i]));
          }
        }
        else {
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
      }
    }

    return '?' + str.join("&");
  }

  extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    // console.log("body", body)
    return body || {};
  }

  handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

BUT i have socket library that configures the socket URL in the

> app.module.ts

so when I try to use dynamic URL(in the app.module.ts) like this:

```
const apiHelper = new ApiHelperService(); //fails here
const url: string = apiHelper.getSocketUrl();
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: url, options: {
  "force new connection" : true,
  "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
  "timeout" : 10000,
  "transports" : ["websocket"]} };
```

it fails with this error:

```
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling 
function 'ApiHelperService', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a
reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule
```

so my question is, is my approach wrong?
what is the right approach to handle this problem?

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: I don't really understand, I launch the app with 'ng serve' and deploy it with 'ng build ...'

Comment: what are you using angular cli for development

Comment: I built the app using 'ng new my-app',
but as far as I understand I made no changes in the config files,
right now, all the changes are made within the Angular app, and the Build version, is the same as development version, just with that minor change of false to true(within an Angular service)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't read the isProduction boolean from your environment file? (eg. Create one environment.development.ts and one environment.production.ts) See here for example: https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

Comment: Yeah, that looks like exactly what I need, Thank You :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it works in different way: [alligator.io/angular/environment-variables](http://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables)

you must specify variables in **environment.ts** and **environment.prod.ts**

then **import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';**
**environment** object will contain proper variables

Comment: link alligator.io/angular/environment-variables added